# Install PDO on OS X Leopard

Tags: mysql, macos, pdo, modx

What's the easiest way to install PDO on the default php installation of OS X Leopard?  I'm trying to get ModX running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a hassle to build PHP extensions with the Leopard default PHP. If you are just doing development work, look into [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/), which has a whole bunch of extensions (including PDO for MySQL and PostgreSQL) built-in. It includes its own copy of Apache so you won’t be using the OS X default Apache. Don’t worry, there’s no installation needed.

A second option is [Mark Liyanage’s PHP package](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/) which is a PHP module that you use instead of the one that comes with Leopard, but has a lot of extensions built-in.

MAMP is easier, but Liyanage’s package works with the built-in web server.

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but using Entropy (Mark Liyanage's package) worked great.  No conflicts and no problems.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something that's a little bit more robust than MAMP, I'd recommend [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/). It's similar to MAMP, but gives you more control over your server environment.

Comment: Disclaimer: Only for Intel macs.