# phpinfo() different from php-i for pdo_mysql

Tags: php

I have a serious problem when installing my php extension pdo_mysql.

my phpinfo() shows that mysql is not enabled, but when i do php-i, or php-m , mysql is enabled.
I've checked my php.ini, and I've made the correct changes in the correct loaded php.ini:
my extension_dir, and extension= are correct too.

My OS : mac os x 10.5

I cannot understand why mysql isn't enabled in my phpinfo()!!
Please help me on this one, i've been stuck for days!

Comment: Are you sure PHP is indeed reading the ini file? PHP is able to
work without any php.ini, it may be the case the the ini file is misplaced and not reading correctly.

Comment: Yes, because if I change the extension_dir, the changes show in the phpinfo(), so I know that i'm editing the right php.ini...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php.ini used by the command line and the web server may not be the same. Check the phpinfo's "Loaded Configuration File" to make sure you're editing the right one.

Check the lines:

pdo_mysql.default_socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock

mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

mysqli.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

OSX creates the mysql.sock in /tmp/mysql.sock by default, so you may need to update those lines.

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick respone. I've already checked and yes I'm editing the correct php.ini

Comment: On mac's you quite often have to edit the mysql.sock that php.ini is pointing to by default it's created at /tmp/mysql.sock http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html

Comment: Yes, i've edited thoses lines with /tmp/mysq.sock bit I don't have the pdo_mysql.default_socket line, should i add it ? Even if i add, it, after restarting apache, nothing has changed, phpinfo doesnot show mysql enabled

Comment: How have you installed php and how are you installing the pdo extension?

Comment: php was already installed, so i've just downloaded the pdo extensions following those steps

1. Download PDO_MYSQL / http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_MYSQL
2. cd ~/Downloads/PDO_MYSQL-x.x.x/PDO_MYSQL-x.x.x
3. phpize
4. ./configure '--with-pdo-mysql=shared
5. make
6. sudo make install

Comment: ok i'm on it, but do i need to uninstall my current version of php ? or will it override it ?

Comment: I can't say for certain but it could be your pdo_mysql installation. I'm not sure if php needs to be installed with that option in the configure arguments. I use Homebrew: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/. Or there's a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280609/install-pdo-on-os-x-leopard

Comment: You can leave your existing php installation. The homebrew installation will be used instead.

Comment: ok, so when i try to install homebrew it says /usr/local/bin is not in your PATH., but it is...

Comment: Was that just a warning? You checked `echo $PATH`

Comment: but isn't it strange that mysql is enabled when i run php-i, or php-m ? doesn"t it mean that my pdo_mysql installation went well at some point? Here is my echo $PATH = /usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: mysql and pdo_mysql are two different things. mysql will allow you to use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php pdo_mysql will allow you to use http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php with mysql.

Comment: yes, but in my php -i, mysql is enabled in pdo drivers.., pdo_mysql is enabled

Comment: That does seem strange. Maybe try the -c option as well on command line and point it to the php.ini you've been editing.

Comment: if i do php -c /private/etc, it runs forever without showing anything

Comment: `php -c /private/etc/php.ini -i`

Comment: this is the output interesting : PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, sqlite2, mysql

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL, client library version => 5.1.54

Comment: I'm not sure where else to head with it. I know homebrew or another packaging system doesn't solve the why, but it will be useful when you need to add other extensions not included in the default osx install.

Comment: ok... Well, anyway, thank you so much for spending time on this with me, it was really kind of you! I don't reaaly know what to do now...:(

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more, but I'd go for macports or homebrew. Then you can install additional extension easily. i.e. on macports `port install php5-mysql` and it should work straight away.

Comment: hey, so i've installed everything via macport, but now, my new version of php is 5.3.5, but my phpinfo stilll shows me the 5.2.14 version. How can I change that ?

Comment: did you follow any guide to install it? could be as simple as restarting apache.

Comment: Yes, i think so... Actually, maybe im afraid to change everuthing... should i do a sudo port load apache2 to tell my computer to use the newly installed apache ?

Comment: Oh yea I think macports installs a new apache, so you'll have to stop the old one, and start the new one.

Comment: You will probably have to update the new apache configuration to point to the same as the old one. Then restart apache again.

Comment: http://2tbsp.com/content/install_apache_2_and_php_5_macports see "Configure Apache and PHP 5"

Comment: It works !!!!!!! Everything works now !!!! Thank you SO much for everything, you've been very patient with me, I'm so releived, I cannot thank you enough